# How to parse values to decimal and sum the values in webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, parsing, decimal

I have a web service and in web service code, i parse string values, sum the values and return the result.

> -400 (string in database => parse in ws code => to decimal)
>
> +400 (string in database => parse in ws code => to decimal)
>
> Sum = 0

But when i try to test webservice in another project, i get the `result = "39600"` actual result should be `0`.

How should i solve this?

My code is:

```
var Result = AmountTbl.Sum(a => decimal.Parse(a.Amount)).ToString();

return Result;
```

Comment: have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @wudzik yes i did.  it didnt work. the other results are true, like -1200, 400 etc. but i cant return "0" result.

Comment: `40 000 + -400 = 39600` Seems it's getting 40000 instead of 400.00.

Comment: @Valentin yes, it seems so... edit: values are -400, 100,16 and 299,84 so any idea?

Comment: @ickr90 How `400` is stored in database?

Comment: @Valentin, its data type is string :/ i parse the values in code. and sum. values are negative and positive.     -400, 12,86, 400, -12,86...etc.

Comment: @ickr90 and what is `Amount` type?

Comment: string in db. @Valentin

Comment: @ickr90 and in the model? Can you sho the model class?

Comment: model class=>  public string Amount { get; set; }        i parse string (db value) to decimal, sum and convert to string again  and then return the string value.     but even if i dont convert to string  and  i define datatype as decimal in model class, it doesnt work. @Valentin

Comment: @ickr90 Can you run the `AmountTbl.Select(decimal.Parse).ToList()` and check the values?

Comment: @Valentin, it shows right values: -400,   100,16     ,   299,84   and sum value = 0 so i get the right result.    but when i publish the service on IIS, and test it, i get the result 39600